# How do I make a python dataclass inherit __hash__?

Tags: python, hash, data-class

The following will work, but I'd rather not need to repeat the `__hash__` in each subclass.  Is there a way to tell the dataclass to inherit the hash function (i.e. not set it to `None`)?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Hashable:

    def __hash__(self):
        hashed = hash((
            getattr(self, key)
            for key in self.__annotations__
            ))
        return hashed


@dataclass
class Node(Hashable):
    name: str = 'Undefined'

    def __hash__(self):
        return Hashable.__hash__(self)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to define that hash yourself? It's basically a buggier, less safe version of what you'd get if you set `frozen=True`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *reason* your `__hash__` is being set to `None` is that `dataclasses` is trying to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. Your second class has `eq=True` for the dataclass decorator (this is the default value). From the docs:

> Here are the rules governing implicit creation of a `__hash__()` method.
>   Note that you cannot both have an explicit `__hash__()` method in your
>   dataclass and set unsafe_hash=True; this will result in a `TypeError`.
>
> If eq and frozen are both true, by default dataclass() will generate a
>   `__hash__()` method for you. **If eq is true and frozen is false, __hash__() will be set to None, marking it unhashable (which it is, since it is mutable).** If eq is false, `__hash__()` will be left
>   untouched meaning the `__hash__()` method of the superclass will be used
>   (if the superclass is `object`, this means it will fall back to id-based
>   hashing).

So just pass `eq=False`:

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: @dataclass
   ...: class Hashable:
   ...:
   ...:     def __hash__(self):
   ...:         hashed = hash((
   ...:             getattr(self, key)
   ...:             for key in self.__annotations__
   ...:             ))
   ...:         return hashed
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: @dataclass(eq=False)
   ...: class Node(Hashable):
   ...:     name: str = 'Undefined'
   ...:

In [2]: hash(Node())
Out[2]: -9223372036579626267
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, this isn't very safe, since you have a mutable object that is now hash-able, and inconsistently so with it's implementation of `__eq__`, which it is inheriting from `Hashable`

Comment: I'd say the real problem is that they're defining this `__hash__` at all instead of using `frozen=True`.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree

Comment: @user2357112 This example is necessarily simple.  Its a poor assumption to assume that `frozen` is even a good idea for my use case.

Comment: @BrianBruggeman: Well, your example `__hash__` is buggy (incorrectly handling `ClassVar`, `InitVar`, and inherited fields), and if you specifically don't want `frozen=True`, then it sounds like you want mutable hashable objects, which are usually a bad idea. Even if you don't want `frozen=True`, `unsafe_hash=True` is probably a better idea.

Comment: Unsafe really only handles simple primitives and won't work with more complexity.  I'd like a reusable function I can both test and pass down a chain of subclasses.  having dataclass(eq=False) is actually more obfuscating/less clear than my original example.

Answer (score 0):

Because the accepted answer didn't work for me, here's a slightly less verbose way to write what OP did originally, which did work in my case.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Hashable:
    def __hash__(self):
        ...  # implementation

@dataclass
class Node(Hashable):
    name: str = 'Undefined'
    __hash__ = Hashable.__hash__
```